# Angular velocity doubt

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, angular-velocity

[image: Image 1]

Here is a rod of mass $M$ and of length $l$ resting on a smooth frictionless horizontal table. Now a small bullet of mass $m$ comes and collides inelastically with this rod and here I wanted to find the velocity of the point H just after the bullet gets embedded in the rod.
Now, here first of all as per the image 2, I used the conservation of momentum.I can get the velocity of centre of mass of rod just after collision to be

$$v=mu/(m+M)$$

Also since the body will rotate about the centre of mass with angular velocity $\omega$ (say) and I also know that omega can be easily calculated by using conservation of angular momentum using

$$L_{\text{initial}}=L_{\text{final}}$$

Taking the point of COM to be point $O$

$$mu(OH)=(I_{\text{rod}, O})\omega + m(OH)^2 \omega $$
$I_{\text{rod}, O}$ means moment of inertia about point $O$.

Now I have the angular velocity of the bottommost point after the collision and its distance from the COM, but since the COM is itself moving ahead,I suspect that I can't use $v_{o}=(OH) \omega$. Kindly help me in this regard.

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 1):

You know the angular velocity of the rod and bullet and the linear velocity of the centre of mass of the rod and bullet.

Considering the rotation about the combined  centre of mass you can find the linear velocity relative to that centre of mass of any position on the rod.

Now add the two velocities vectorially.

Answer (score 0):

$I_t$ of rod and bullet immediately after the impact $ = I+ m(Ml/2 +m.0)/(m+M))^2$

and center of rotation $is = (I (L/2)^2 + 0)/I_t $

Conservation of momentum: $mu= I_tw + (m+M)v   $

v is the horizontal velocity immediately after impact.

Also $w. X_{\text{distance to center of rotation}}= v$

So we can solve for v.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I use those four  equations (after the collision )

$$m \left( v-u \right) ={-\it dp}\\
M\,v_{{{\it CM}}}={\it dp}\\
v_{{{\it CM}}}-v=0\\
I_{{E}}\,\omega={\it dp}\,h$$

where $~I_E=I_{CM}+m\,h^2$

you have 4 equations for the unknows $~v~,v_{CM}~,\omega~,dp$  hence :

$$v={\frac {mu}{m+M}}\\
v_{CM}=v\\
\omega={\frac {M\,m\,u\,h}{ \left( m+M \right) I_{{E}}}}\\
dp={\frac {M\,m\,u}{m+M}}
$$

you can check that the conservation of momentum is fulfilled

$$m\,u=m\,v+M\,v_{CM}$$

now to your question

you know the rotation of the rod $~\omega~$ and the velocity of the center of mass
$~v_{CM}~$ , for any point on the rod $~p~$ you obtain the velocity

$$v_p=v_{CM}+\omega\,p$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming point **H** is the point of impact, which is a distance $d$ from the COM of the rod.

[image: fig1]

If the objects exchange an impulse $J$ along the direction of travel of the bullet then the change in velocity due to the impact is

- Translational for the bullet $$\Delta u = - \frac{J}{m}$$
- Translational for the rod at COM $$\Delta v = \frac{J}{M} $$
- Rotational for the rod $$\Delta \omega = \frac{d J}{I}$$
- Translational for the rod at **H** $$\Delta v_H = \Delta v + d\, \Delta \omega$$

  where $I = \tfrac{1}{12} M \ell^2$ is the mass moment of inertia of the rod at the COM.

The above scenario by definition conserves the *total* momentum as $J$ (impulse = exchange of momentum) is applied in equal and opposite measure to both objects in magnitude, direction, and location. The magnitude and direction conserve linear momentum and the location conserves angular momentum.

We find the magnitude of $J$ by using the law of contact the relates the relative velocity after the impact, with the relative velocity before contact.

$$ \underbrace{(u + \Delta u) - (\Delta v_H)}_{\text{after}} = -\epsilon \underbrace{u }_{\text{before}}$$

and by using the above expressions

$$ (u - \frac{J}{m}) - (\frac{J}{M} + \frac{d^2 J}{I}) = -\epsilon u $$

which is solved by

$$ - J \left( \tfrac{1}{m} + \tfrac{1}{M} + \tfrac{d^2}{I} \right) = -(1+\epsilon) u $$

or by using the *reduced mass*

$$ m_{\rm eff} = \frac{1}{\tfrac{1}{m} + \tfrac{1}{M} + \tfrac{d^2}{I} } $$

the solution is

$$ J = ( 1+ \epsilon)\; m_{\rm eff}\, u $$

$$ \Delta v_H = \tfrac{J}{M} + \tfrac{d^2 J}{I} = (1+\epsilon) \left(1 - \tfrac{m_{\rm eff}}{m} \right) u $$

The above is found with some algebraic manipulation, by eliminating $I$ in terms of $m_{\rm eff}$. Curiously I get the following intermediate expression that seems important

$$ \Delta v_H = \frac{J}{M} + \left( \frac{1}{m_{\rm eff}} - \frac{1}{m} - \frac{1}{M} \right) J $$

I am not sure how to interpret this, other than $\frac{1}{m_{\rm eff}}$ includes rotational effects and $\frac{1}{m} + \frac{1}{M}$ does not. The difference of the two somehow adds to the velocity of **H** an additional term beyond $J/M$ which is the velocity of the COM. So this means the second part of this expression represents the additional velocity due to the rotation of the rod.

---

The problem with your approach is that you assumed the reduced mass is $m_{\rm eff} = \frac{1}{ \tfrac{1}{m} + \tfrac{1}{M} }$ which is only valid for point masses. For rigid two rigid bodies it is

$$ m_{\rm eff} = \frac{1}{ \frac{1}{m_1} + \frac{d_1^2}{I_1} + \frac{1}{m_2} + \frac{d_2^2}{I_2} }$$ where $m_1$ and $m_2$ are the two masses, $I_1$ and $I_2$ are the two mass moment of inertias, and $d_1$ and $d_2$ the offset of the impact point to each center of mass.

For this case with one point mass and one rigid body you can ignore one of the $d^2/I$ terms as it vanishes when the impact line goes through the COM of a body and $d=0$.

Then the impulse magnitude is *always* given by $$ J = (1+\epsilon) \; m_{\rm eff}\; v_{\rm imp}$$

where $v_{\rm imp}$ is the relative impact speed.